# Using Mockito Matchers.any() with android.support.annotation.IntDef custom annotation

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to write a Junit test which will verify whether the following method is called:

```
public long executeRequest(@RequestCodes.Code.RequestAnnotation int requestCode, Object requestInformation, RequestListener requestListener) {

    boolean success = false;

    ... do stuff ...

    return success ? 1L : -1L;

}
```

in a test using:

```
Mockito.when(mockedRequest.executeRequest(Matchers.any(RequestCodes.Code.RequestAnnotation.class), Matchers.any(RequestWrapper.class), Matchers.any(RequestListener.class))).thenReturn(1L);
```

The RequestCodes.Code.RequestAnnotation class is a elementary indef interface using an int to identify the call to make using a switch. Pretty much like [this](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2015/10/31/android-intdef-annotation-example/#.V6Cbh8cdQ9Y).

`Matchers.any(RequestCodes.Code.RequestAnnotation.class)` won't work here and I have tried `Matchers.any()`, `Matchers.anyInt()`, `Matchers.isA(RequestCodes.Code.RequestAnnotation.getClass())` (as well as anything else that came to mind) with no success.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: `anyInt()` should definitely work, only Lint will complain. You could also introduce a custom matcher for this use case.

Comment: Came across the very same at work today. Could [issue 222711](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222711) be worth keeping an eye on?

Answer (score 2):

For now, you can suppress this error using `@SuppressWarnings("WrongConstant")` for this specific test. It works fine, and keeps your production clean.